# In clojure, what's the efficient way to convolve a vector by a kernel?

Tags: vector, clojure, linear-algebra, convolution

I came up with this:

```
(def kernel [0 1 1 2 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0])
(def data [1 5 7 4 8 3 9 5 6 3 2 1 1 7 4 9 3 2 1 8 6 4])

(defn capped+ [a b c] (let [s (+ a b)] (if (> s c) c s)))

(defn *+ [a b]
  (if (> (count a) (count b))  
    (reduce + (map-indexed (fn _ [i x] (* (a i) (b i))) b))
    (reduce + (map-indexed (fn _ [i x] (* (a i) (b i))) a))))

(defn slide*i [d k] 
 (let [ki (into [] (reverse k)) kl (count k) dl (count d)]
   (map-indexed 
      (fn [idx item] 
        (/ (*+ ki (subvec d idx (capped+ idx kl dl))) 
           (reduce + ki))) 
      d)))

(def s (slide*i data kernel))
```

It's not the most elegant code, but it works fine.
I actually want to use it to smooth some very spiky! data.

Any suggestions to make this more beautiful or more efficient or more accurate (personally I don't care about the tail being inaccurate because in my case I never use it) are welcomed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can certainly improve the performance of this operation significantly. The good news is that you don't need to drop into Java for this: Clojure is extremely fast if you optimise it correctly and in most instances can produce the same speed as pure Java.

For maximum performance of numerical code in Clojure you will want to use:

- **arrays**, because you want mutable storage with very fast writes and lookup. Clojure sequences and vectors are beautiful, but they come with overheads that you probably want to avoid for truly performance-critical code
- **double** primitives, because they offer much faster maths.
- **aset / aget / areduce** - these are extremely fast operations designed for arrays and basically give you the same bytecode as pure Java equivalents.
- **imperative style** - although it's unidiomatic in Clojure, it gets the fastest results (mainly because you can avoid overheads from memory allocations, boxing and function calls). An example would be using [dotimes](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/dotimes) for a fast imperative loop.
- **(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)** - and eliminate any warnings your code produces, because reflection is a big performance killer.

The following should be along the right lines and will probably get you roughly equivalent performance to Java:

```
(def kernel (double-array [0 1 1 2 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0]))
(def data (double-array [1 5 7 4 8 3 9 5 6 3 2 1 1 7 4 9 3 2 1 8 6 4]))

(defn convolve [^doubles kernel-array ^doubles data-array]
  (let [ks (count kernel-array)
        ds (count data-array)
        output (double-array (+ ks ds))
        factor (/ 1.0 (areduce kernel-array i ret 0.0 (+ ret (aget kernel-array i))))]    
    (dotimes [i (int ds)]
      (dotimes [j (int ks)]
        (let [offset (int (+ i j))]
          (aset output offset (+ (aget output offset) (* factor (* (aget data-array i) (aget kernel-array j))))))))
    output))

(seq (convolve kernel data))
=> (0.0 0.1 0.6 1.4 2.4 4.4 5.5 6.1000000000000005 5.600000000000001 6.200000000000001 5.499999999999999 5.9 4.199999999999999 3.3000000000000003 2.5 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.6000000000000005 4.8 4.8999999999999995 3.1 3.5 4.300000000000001 5.0 3.0 1.2000000000000002 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0)
```

I've not trimmed the output array or done any bounding so you'll probably need to hack this solution a bit to get exactly the output you want, but hopefully you get the idea.....

Some very rough benchmarking:

```
(time (dotimes [i 1000] (seq (convolve kernel data))))
=> "Elapsed time: 8.174109 msecs"
```

i.e. that's about 30ns per kernel / data pair combination - I expect that's pretty much hitting the bounds of cached memory access.

Comment: fantastic answer, very comprehensive comments. What is that `^doubles` thing in the `defn`?  And to make it clear for me, you mean I'd better get as close as possible to the way I would have implemented it in java, right? I mean basically nested `for` loops.

Comment: The ^doubles is a type hint to indicate a primitive double array. it helps the compiler optimise the aget methods. and yes, nested for loops and array mutation is basically the fastest way to solve this particular problem. Not very Clojure-y but it works!

Comment: The surprising thing to me is how this isn't much faster than the simple HOF approach below, especially when enabling `*unchecked-math*` (new in 1.3).

Comment: interesting - what timing did you get Alex? I also noticed that my algorithm above is more write-intensive than it needs to be so there is potentially another possible speedup.

Answer (score 4):

```
; unused, but left for demonstration
(defn capped+ [a b c]
  (min (+ a b) c))

(defn *+ [a b]
  (reduce + (map * a b)))

(defn slide*i [d k]
  (let [ki (reverse k)
        kl (count k)
        ks (reduce + k)]
    (map #(/ (*+ %1 ki) ks) (partition kl 1 d))))
```

With `partition`, the results are:

```
(59/10 21/5 33/10 5/2 11/5 33/10 22/5 28/5 24/5 49/10 31/10)
```

But with `partition-all`, you'll get exactly what your solution resulted in:

```
(59/10 21/5 33/10 5/2 11/5 33/10 22/5 28/5 24/5 49/10 31/10 7/2 43/10 5 3 6/5 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

Comment: Usually (for the type of things I do at least) the kernel is way shorter than the data vector (like a kernel with 100 points and data with 2000 paints). And be definition for convolution you need to revers (clojure) the kernel before you slide it over (although in the majority of cases kernel is symmetric so you don't need to do that, or you can have your kernel reversed to begin with to save time and resources).

Comment: Is there something you see lacking in my solution?

Comment: Looks like it works fine, and more elegant than mine, for sure.

Comment: If `k` is a vector, you might also use `rseq` instead of `reverse`. But if `k` is only 100 elements it should be thaaat of an improvement. `rseq` is O(1) on vectors, while `reverse` is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way of doing this is to create java class that does convolution and call it from clojure, passing it a java array if possible. Clojure implementation should operate on java arrays as well if efficiency is a concern.

Comment: Thanks @Looka , Although I didn't want to hear that! I don't like and I don't know (much) java, and if wanted to use java I would have been better off using c# or Objective-C or C++ or ... maybe I am getting too attached to the clojure way of thinking (which I am learning).

Comment: If you look at http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=clojure
you will notice that most clojure solutions use java arrays (and still don't match java for CPU or memory efficiency. 
If you use normal clojure code you will produce tons and tons of small allocations just iterating through a sequence - adding a lot of execution time from allocations, GC triggering. All the allocations clojure does also result in large memory footprint, which will cause tons of cache misses - cache miss costs 20-100 normal memory accesses. Painful when convoluting on large datasets.